# What happens when you add an iframe or table to a Stack Overflow post?

Tags: testing, iframe

This question is about to answer itself. I'm seeing what happens here. The youtube video has nothing to do with my question. Does the below iframe text even appear after I hit the publish button?

---

This is the code for the iframe:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3m1JoFf-poQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And this is how it displays:

This is a table with the following code:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And this is how it displays:

Firstname
    Lastname 
    Age
  
  
    Jill
    Smith 
    50
  
  
    Eve
    Jackson 
    94

Comment: I'm happy to move this question to another site if people think that's a good idea. I'm really just testing how SO handles arbitrary html from users since I have a problem involving arbitrary html from my own users.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

The preview shows me what actually gets displayed after publishing. The html that I wrote that did not get into the published post remained in my question when I went to edit it so it's not being destroyed by some scrubber, simply not sent for rendering.

Here's an explanation of what's allowed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites